# The file “embedded.mobileprovision” couldn’t be saved in the folder “Watch Badge Extension.appex”

Tags: xcode, ipa, sign

I get this error when I tried to sign the ipa file. Not sure what could be the actual reason.

```
The file “embedded.mobileprovision” couldn’t be saved in the folder “Watch Badge Extension.appex”.
```

Answer (score 2):

I have just restarted xCode and everything works fine again